Why does a tailwind breakpoint affect another unrelated component?
I have a VueJS frontend with tailwindCSS. There is a component that's used twice in the page.
<ApplicationLogo class="h-16 w-auto" />

and
<div class="hidden lg:block">
    <ApplicationLogo class="mr-6 h-8 w-auto"/>
</div>

Both of these disappear when the viewport size is less than 1024px. Why is that?
ApplicationLogo is an SVG. When I replace that SVG with some text only one disappears as expected.

Please, provide a way to reproduce. It's unknown what happens on your side.

I have Isolated the problem to the SVG I'm using because if I swap the SVG for some other simple SVG, everything is fine. The SVG I'm using exceeds 30000 characters. I can't even add it to the question. Could that be the problem? I created the SVG in Figma.

https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/068AsSB3IncRBgl6GQHHrO9DQ#ApplicationLogo
this is the SVG.

You can use a service like stackblitz or a repo to host bigger data. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, SVG itself is not enough, I see no reason for it to work the way you described, it needs to be shown
